# Filter with Jquery Autocomplete, Remote Source

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

So, i have implemented "Jquery Autocomplete" to my input field.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="objekt_nr">
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#objekt_nr" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'file.php',
        minLength: 2,
    });
});
```

After some reading (no info in the docs) on google, i understand that you need to have the filter in "Server Side" php script. And i use some filtering there.

**PHP**

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT column1 as value FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '".$term."%'";
```

My problem is that the "catch" is only filtering the very first or maby second charater.
And as i type, the miss fitting characters won´t filter out.

Example: I type in 2133.. no i can also see: 2135..
How can i solve this?
Do i need to write my own `on keyup, function`?
Because i cannot find anything about this in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want it to filter based on partial matches ( eg when you type `2133`, to show results for `2`, `21`, `213`, and `2133` ).

Assuming the above is true, you don't need to do anything in jQuery - entirely in PHP. So, modifying your code above :

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
for($i=1; $i<=strlen($term); $i++) {
  $test_term = substr($term, 0, $i);
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT column1 as value FROM table 
             WHERE column1 LIKE '".$test_term."%'";
}
```

Comment: Works very well! Thank u!